# PHP add time issue

Tags: php, date, addition

I'm trying to add time to the last modified time of a particular textfile ( where $filename is said textfile ), essentially this

```
$txt_time = date("Y-m-d H:i", filemtime($filename));
$add_time = $txt_time + [5minutes];
```

i've tried this

```
$add_time = date_add($txt_time, new DateInterval("T5M"));
```

but that doesn't seem to work
any ideas?

Comment: `$add_time = $txt_time + [5minutes];` <--- what's this?

Comment: I am sure this should work. `return date("d", filemtime($file_to_read)` Have you tried it like this?

Comment: You would be amazed as to what can be found by entering this in Google's search input: **"add 5 minutes to time php"**

Comment: @Allendar I have no formal training with this stuff, what do you mean by OOP? Object Oriented Programming? if so what do you mean by "Use OOP" I'm sorry that I don't understand this

Comment: @Fred-ii- of course I tried google first, most of the results explain how to add time to the current time, my issue is specifically with adding time to the modified file time ( which doesn't seem to work when I use the conventional methods for adding time which I found on Google )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IMSoP I couldn't get your suggestions to work, while your live demo works, I couldn't get it to work when I used it with an actual filemtime($filename)

@Fabio your suggestion set me off on the right track, "+5 minutes" seems to work but not when I use strtotime() instead I was able to get it to work this way:

```
$add_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime($filename) + "300 seconds");
```

thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add the minutes in `date()` function

```
$txt_time = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime(filemtime($filename).'+ 5 minutes'));
```

Comment: They should really make an alt-documentation for PHP where all procedural stuff is removed :P +1 tho

Comment: @Allendar That would be pretty useless for the 90% of the core functions which have no direct OO equivalent. And since `filemtime()` returns a plain integer, that includes this case. The existence of `date_add` as a procedural function explicitly for dealing with objects does seem unnecessary though.

Comment: More importantly, while it looks plausible, this solution won't actually work: `filemtime()` returns a Unix timestamp as an integer, so you end up passing a string like `'1234567890+5 minutes'` to `strtotime`, which won't do anything very useful: http://codepad.viper-7.com/eiOa7M

Comment: You can amend this approach to work by using an extra call to `date()`, although it's a bit ugly, particularly if you leave it all on one line: [`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1234567890) . '+5 minutes'));`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qf6h5S)

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the PHP manual, [`date_add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) takes as its first argument a [DateTime object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), but [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) returns a `string`, so no, the code you wrote won't work.

Instead, you need to use [`date_create_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) with the `'U'` format specifier to create an object from the return value of [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/filemtime), which is an integer Unix timestamp.

```
$txt_time = date_create_from_format('U', filemtime($filename));
date_add($txt_time, new DateInterval("PT5M"));
echo date_format($txt_time, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But beware! The `$txt_time` variable will be *modified* by the `date_add` operation.

You can also use the OOP version of the same code, which makes it a bit clearer why the in-place modification is happening:

```
$txt_time = DateTime::create_from_format('U', filemtime($filename));
$txt_time->add(new DateInterval("PT5M"));
echo $txt_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If you are on PHP 5.5, you can create a `DateTimeImmutable` object instead, which will return the new value as you originally planned, leaving the original variable untouched:

```
$txt_time = DateTimeImmutable::create_from_format('U', filemtime($filename));
$add_time = $txt_time->add(new DateInterval("PT5M"));
echo $add_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Note:** You were also providing slightly the wrong format to create the `DateInterval`, it should always begin with `P`, so should be `"PT5M"`. I've updated the examples above.

Here's [a live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qiVDMk) where I checked the first version of the code ran correctly.

Comment: An interval specification `T5M` doesn't exists, and it will not work. It should be `PT5M`.

Comment: @Glavić I just spotted that myself; I'd copied it from the question without testing, and was about to add a note to that effect :)